# Visiting New Zealand, unable to install

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I am currently on a trip in New Zealand and I wanted to install Pokémon GO here from the regular Google Play Store since in my home place (DE) it is not yet released. But I keep getting it not offered.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to change your google play details not simply be in another country.

See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country for details on how to possibly do this.

However, the New Zealand servers are currently pretty overloaded with international users, not just us Kiwis...